# Check if one line contains a part of the other

Tags: algorithm, sorting, logic, intervals

Given two horizontal lines on a 1 dimension plane. I want to check if they overlap at any point.

Below I show some examples of overlap. Please note that, intervals like `[1,2]` and `[2,3]` have borders "touching" but they don't overlap each other.
`[1,2]` is basically a line going from 1 on the x axis, to 2 on the x axis.

[image]

My question is, what are the exhaustive set of checks for such a condition. These are the ones I came up with, assuming that the first line is called, a, and the second line is called b.

```
b.s <= a.s && b.e > a.s
b.s <= a.s && b.e >= a.e
b.s < a.e && b.e >= a.e
b.s > a.s && b.e < a.s
```

Is it really this complicated? Isn't there an easier way to figure out if two lines overlap/one line contains a part of the other?

**Aliter**
By looking at the negation condition

```
    public boolean isOverlap(Interval i1, Interval i2)
    {   
//        if(i2.start <= i1.start && i2.end > i1.start)
//            return true;
//        
//        if(i2.start <= i1.start && i2.end >= i1.end)
//            return true;
//        
//        if(i2.start < i1.end && i2.end >= i1.end)
//            return true;
//        
//        if(i2.start >= i1.start && i2.end <= i1.end)
//            return true;
//        
//        return false;

        if(i2.start <= i1.start && i2.end <= i1.start)
            return false;

        if(i2.start >= i1.end && i2.end >= i1.end)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: `a.s < b.e and b.s < a.e`.

Comment: @n.m. thanks for replying, but is this another condition that's to be added?

Comment: No, this is the entire condition. It replaces your check. It assumes a.s < a.e and b.s < b.e (if not, swap start and end).

Comment: You can see that it's enough to check if a start point is into the other line, so you only need the conditions 

    `if (l1.s > l2.s and l1.s < l2.e) or (l2.s > l1.s and l2.s < l1.e)
        return true`

Comment: @EmmanuelAC You need `>=` in both places you use `>`: `l1.s >= l2.s`,  `l2.s >= l1.s` (`<` stays `<`). The resulting expression is equivalent to `(l1.s < l2.e) and (l2.s < l1.e)`.

Comment: Apparently I assumed positive interval length. Do you allow zero length intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative method is to consider them on the same axis and check for disconnectedness.

Then you can say "what is the left most point?"

I'll use .l for "left" and .r for "right."

```
leftmost = a.l < b.l ? a : b
rightmost = leftmost == a ? b : a
```

Now you know the left most one and the right most one.  In order for them to be connected the right most one must have a left part in between the the left and right of the leftmost one.

Assuming every line must have at least length 1 then you can simply do:

```
connected = rightmost.l < leftmost.r
```

Comment: not sure if I completely understood your post, but the word disconnectedness you used, gave me an idea, to check for the negation condition, since it's much less than the number of positive scenarios for overlap. Surprisingly, I get the same answer. Which means, either both are right, or both are wrong :) Please take a look at the edit above, and let me know what you think.

Comment: That should work.  You could also reduce it further to a single line.  N.M's version seems to work.

Comment: Why not `connected = (rightmost.l < leftmost.r ? true : false) ? true : false` ?

Comment: connected = ((rightmost.l < leftmost.r ? true : false) ? true : false) ? true : false would be even better.  I was sleepy.